# Which String methods got changed with Arduino 1.0?

Tags: arduino, programming

It seems that several of the `String` methods (so far I'm sure it applies to `trim()` and the to upper/lower functions) in the Arduino library have been modified to alter the String rather than return a new one. Is there a complete list of which methods have been modified? The release notes have the following unhelpful statement:

> - The String class has been reimplemented as well, by Paul Stoffregen. This   new version is more memory-efficient and robust. Some functions
>     which   previously returned new string instances (e.g. trim() and
>     toUpperCase())   have been changed to instead modify strings in place.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking trough the source code of [WString.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/WString.cpp) of the current version... That way you'll get up to date informations from the first hand...

Answer (score 1):

At least in the MAC OSX and Windows version, there is no documentation in the reference folder for the String class. That certainly can lead to confusion about the new String class when you receive no documentation in the distribution.

However the files are posted in the reference section on-line.  I expect your questions may well be answered there if you do no care to delve into the source code, (although the source is the ultimate resource.)